# multiprocess on read or write csv

Tags: python, performance, csv, multiprocessing

So right now I'm working on a python code, which reads a csv file, do something, then saved in another csv file. I have more than 5000 large csv file to process.

I'm thinking using the multiprocess package, running at least 200 files at a same time, to help me save time. However, it's not running multiple threads at the same time as I though it will, here is my pseudo code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(inputfile,outputfile):
    open inputfile as reader
    open outputfile as writer
    #do sth

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for a list of inputfile_names/outputfile_names:
          p=Process(target=f,args=(input_names,output_names,))
          p.start()
          p.join()
```

I have little knowledge on python multiprocess or threads and I don't know if I'm using the right package or whatever.

Please help me, thank you!

(also I'm running this on ubuntu vm, so I'm wondering if there's any shell script can do the same thing and which is faster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the join outside the for loop otherwise you're joining each process immediately after it is initiated

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def f(inputfile,outputfile):
    open inputfile as reader
    open outputfile as writer
    #do sth

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    for a list of inputfile_names/outputfile_names:
          p=Process(target=f,args=(input_names,output_names,))
          p.start()
          processes.append(p)
    #sleep an increment of time until all processes are done
    while len(p for p in processes if p.is_alive()) > 0:
          sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: If you don't mind, it's running correctly right now, but I don't see it's saving any time....before that it's running 12 min for one file, and right now it's like the sum up the time of the individual processes.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is not disk access in that case? It may be a good follow up question to ask separately. You can do some dirty debugging by continually showing progress for each of the processes every, say, 100 processed lines with a process id in the log to make sure the parallelism is working as expected.